# Rational 7.5 Doesn't launch after installing Aptana plugin

Tags: plugins, aptana, ibm-rad, ibm-rational

I installed the Aptana plugin into Rational 7.5, using the help menu install function (not the separate IBM Installation Manager). It seemed to install successfully, then suggested that I restart Rational. I click the "YES" to restart button. Rational closed, but never restarted. I tried to open Rational, but nothing seems to happen. I looked in the event viewer, but I didn't see any error messages related to Rational. I tried starting Rational with the -clean option, but that didn't make any difference. Any ideas about what went wrong? Can I remove the plugin manually (since I can't start Rational to remove it from the help menu)?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Rational. Apparently that Aptana plugin doesn't play well with Rational 7.5, or I did something wrong...

Comment: For those wanting Aptana in Rational, I eventually got brave enough to try again - I successfully installed version 2.0.5 in my Rational version 7.5.5.5 iFix1. It seems to work fine so far. I believe my mistake before was trying to install the latest Aptana version 3.4.2 into Rational 7.5.5.5 iFix1. I don't think Aptana 3 works with Rational 7.5.5.5 iFix1, although it was odd that Rational wouldn't even launch to allow me to uninstall Aptana 3. Not going to try it again though, it takes hours to reinstall Rational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully installed Aptana version 2.0.5 plugin in my Rational version 7.5.5.5 iFix1. It seems to work fine so far.

I believe my mistake before was trying to install the latest Aptana version 3.4.2 into Rational 7.5.5.5 iFix1. I don't think Aptana 3 works with Rational 7.5.5.5 iFix1, although it was odd that Rational wouldn't even launch to allow me to uninstall Aptana 3. Not going to try it again though, it takes hours to reinstall Rational!